# how to use xml with intents?

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

I'm writing an application which I want to be able to launch a second class with a different layout when a menu button is pressed. the code I have to switch classes is:

```
     case Menubutton1:
        Intent i = new Intent(Budgeter.this, Outgoings.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
```

(Obviously within a case statement)

How do I create an xml file which only relates to the second class? Also do I need to edit AndroidManifest.xml?

Finally if anyone could point me towards some good tutorials on intents I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here that you're confused about thinking the layout file for an Activity has to be called main.xml??? If so, this is not the case...

You can have `budgeter.xml`, `outgoings.xml` etc etc.

Just use `setContentView(R.layout.budgeter)` in the Budgeter Activity's `onCreate(...)` method and `setContentView(R.layout.outgoings)` in the Outgoings Activity `onCreate(...)` and so on.

> Also do I need to edit AndroidManifest.xml?

Yes, all Activities must be registered in AndroidManifest.xml

As for working with Intents, try this as a starter...

[Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 1):

in first class write a method

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem mnuHome =menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Home");
        mnuHome.setAlphabeticShortcut('h');
        mnuHome.setIcon(R.drawable.home_icon);

      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getTitle() == "Home") {

            Intent i = new Intent(Budgeter.this, Outgoings.class);
                        startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    }
```

And in second class you have to override onCreate() method and there you can set Layout as

```
setContentView(R.Layout.XML);
```

Also for second class you have to define in `menifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

you should add the second(any) class in AndroidManifest.xml file if the class extended from android core components(Activity,Service,ContentProvider,BroadcastReceiver,BroadcastReceiver is a little different).It is possible to create another XML file in "layout" under "res".